# VSFTPD, 553 Could not create file. - permissions?

Tags: permissions, amazon-ec2, vsftpd

I've set up `vsftpd` on Amazon EC2 with the Amazon Linux AMI. I created a user and can now successfully connect via ftp. However, if I try to upload something I get the error message

```
553 Could not create file.
```

I assume this has to do with permissions, but I don't know enough about it to be able to fix it. So basically, what do I have to do to be able to upload files?

Comment: Check the selinux Settings. configure boolean allow_ftpd_full_access to ON

Comment: i had this issue because there was not enough space to write the files.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two likely reasons that this could happen -- you do not have write and execute permissions on the directories leading to the directory you are trying to upload to, or `vsftpd` is configured not to allow you to upload.

In the former case, use `chmod` and `chown` as appropriate to make sure that your user has these permissions on every intermediate directory. The write bit allows the affected user to create, rename, or delete files within the directory, and modify the directory's attributes, whilst the read bit allows the affected user to list the files within the directory. Since intermediate directories in the path also affect this, the permissions must be set appropriately leading up to the ultimate destination that you intend to upload to.

In the latter case, look at your `vsftpd.conf`. `write_enable` must be true to allow writing (and it is false by default). There is good documentation on this configuration file at `man 5 vsftpd.conf`.

Comment: Neither of these seem to be the issue. I tried chmoding everything to 777 (unsafe) and settings write_enable=YES, but I still get this useless error message.

Comment: @Cerin were you able to fix it? If yes, can you share the details?

Answer (score 53):

Could you try this

```
chown -R ftpusername /var/www/html
```

Comment: chmod 757 -R /var/www/html

Comment: @HernánEche thanks for the tip, I had been hunting for hours and this finally fixed my issue.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the situation, is this on the server or locally?

Comment: @HernánEche Hey, It worked for me too, but is it secure. It wasn't working with 755

Comment: @HernánEche you should make this a separate answer. Your suggestion worked for me where nothing else did.

Comment: thanks, to avoid comments notifications, here it is, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439992/13620

Comment: sudo chown -R ftpusername /var/www/html worked for me.

Comment: if you get an _“500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()”_ error as I did, change the root directory to _/var/www/_ and upload files with `put myfile html/myfile`

Comment: chmod -R 755 /var/www/html  , 7 is 111 read/write/execute, 5 is 101 read/execute, the values are user/group/everyone, the final value being everyone, I don't think it should be 7

Comment: Worked for me, thank you so much @Tacettin Özbölük

Answer (score 14):

The command `ftp put /path/to/local_file` doesn't work with `vsftpd`. Try the following:

```
ftp put /path/to/local_file remote_file_name
```

You may choose any name you wish for the `remote_file_name`, but you must specify one.

Comment: You might want to consider adding more detail to your answer (for example, some documentation that supports your solution's validity).

Comment: This happens because (and if) `/path/to/` doesn't exist (and/or isn't accessible through the FTP session) on the server.  This is why `ftp put local_file` *does* work without explicit destination.  (Hint : check the `local: … remote: …` line in the FTP client.)

Comment: It worked for me! :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and fixed changing SELinux to allow writing in the folder I configured to be used by `vsftp = /var/ftp/pub`.

These links can be helpful:

- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/ftpd
- http://prithak.blogspot.com/2013/07/installation-and-configuration-of.html

If you don't want to go further with your SELinux do not change it, so you will see as default `/etc/selinux/config`

```
SELINUX=enforcing
```

then just run the commands as root or with `sudo`:

```
sudo setsebool -P ftpd_anon_write 1
sudo setsebool -P ftpd_full_access 1
```

as already described above in other comment.

Answer (score 3):

The FTP home directory (ftp_home_dir) is most likely turned off in SeLinux. To see status of your `ftpd` control files, issue: `getsebool -a` and locate the ftpd section. You may notice ftp_home_dir is turned off. To turn it on, use the following command: `setsebool -P ftp_home_dir=1`

Verify your input using `getsebool -a`, then Try the upload again.

Note:
Ignore the punctuation marks

Answer (score 3):

Check your `vsftpd.conf` for this setting:

```
guest_enable=YES # set it to NO then restart the vsftpd service.
```

If it's set to `YES`, it will also cause the `553 Could not create file`.

From: http://www.vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html

> **guest_enable**    If enabled, all non-anonymous logins are
>   classed as "guest" logins. A guest login is remapped to the user
>   specified in the guest_username setting.
>
> **Default: NO**

Comment: if the user is "virtual" you can also chown the chroot dir (i.e `local_root`) to allow write from `guest_username` (by default `ftp`), e.g: `chown ftp /var/ftp/<virtual_user>`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
chmod 757 -R /var/www/html
```

Comment: chmod -R 755 /var/www/html , 7 is 111 read/write/execute, 5 is 101 read/execute, the values are user/group/everyone, the final value being everyone, I don't think it should be 7

Answer (score 1):

The next parameter will give ftpd access to write anywhere:

```
setsebool -P ftpd_full_acess=true
```

Do not use `ftpd_anon_write` unless you want anonymous uploads to be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was with filesystem.

There was a space but filesystem run out of inodes
`df -i`

```
# df -i
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvdf1     3276800 3276800      0  100% /ftp-data01
```

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora23 run the commands:

```
setsebool -P ftpd_anon_write 1 
setsebool -P ftpd_full_access 1
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility : check disk quotas for the user/group

ext:

```
repquota -a
```

xfs:

```
xfs_quota -x -c 'report' /mount_point
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely to have unsupported characters in filename

Answer (score 0):

In my case, **the ftp user had no permissions in the directory it was in**.

I just had forgotten to cd into the target directory, which I **did** have the right permissions for.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (CentOS7 + vsftpd) changing directory permissions to 775 by command "chmod 775 /home/user/ftpdir/" not helped.

I checked selinux status by command "sestatus", it was enabled, i list ftp related options: "getsebool -a|grep ftp"

and enabled the disabled option ftpd_full_access by command "setsebool ftpd_full_access on". Then it started writing the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
nano /etc/vsftpd.conf

# modify these lines
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES

# add these lines
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
```

add the user to /etc/vsftpd.userlist

```
usermod --home /var/www/html/ username
chown -R username /var/www/html
chmod -R 755 /var/www/html
```

7 is user, 5 is group, 5 is other

7 is binary 111, 5 is binary 101

111 = read (yes), write (yes), execute (yes)

101 = read (yes), write (no), execute (yes)

So, the user can read, write, execute but other people can't write.