# CentOS 6 VSFTP 553 Could not create file

Tags: centos, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I installed vsftpd yesterday on CentOS 6, however didn't get a chance to test it today.  When I went to upload a test file it's coming back and giving me this error:

> 553 Could not create file

After some quick googling the information I found on resolving the error, including [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39466/vsftpd-553-could-not-create-file-permissions) were already things I tried...

- Confirm user that is connecting to FTP is a part of the group that owns the directory
- Confirm the `vsftpd.conf` file has `write_enable` set to `true`

I even went so far as to test changing the group on the whole path down to the destination folder.

> ***EDIT:***
>
> Just to expand on this, at the time I did ensure that the modes on the
>   directories were set appropriately as well.
>
> What I ended up doing was uninstalling vsftpd and re-installing from
>   yum.  After I did this things worked appropriately.  So I'm convinced
>   it was a setting in `vsftpd.conf` file.  However I didn't save a copy
>   of it to do a diff off of to confirm.
>
> Hopefully someone else who has had the same problem with the same
>   symptoms and found out what the cause was can accurately answer this
>   question here for someone else who comes along.

Comment: I haved this same problem, See this answers [https://stackoverflow.com/a/54671893/3257556](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54671893/3257556)

Answer (score 4):

That group should have rwx permissions on that folder. If not run

```
chmod 775 <directory>
```

Comment: While technically correct, and I should edit the original question to highlight this, this did not resolve the issue at the time either.

What I ended up doing was uninstalling vsftpd, and reinstalling through yum again.  After that everything worked appropriately.  Leading me to believe that the issue was in the conf file somewhere.  However I unfortunately didn't save the original vsftpd.conf to do a diff between the two.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run the following commands to allow in SELinux upload and edit files:

```
setsebool -P allow_ftpd_full_access on
setsebool -P ftp_home_dir on
```

Comment: Did the trick for me. However, it's `tftp_home_dir` by now.

Answer (score 0):

in the ftp root dir

```
setsebool -P tftp_home_dir on
setsebool -P ftpd_full_access on
```

did work for me

Answer (score -1):

```
setsebool -P ftpd_full_access 1
```

Comment: Can you please extend you answer. One line answer with just a command is not counted as helpful